# Example of OLS vs GLS with AR1 residuals for teaching in R

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, generalized-least-squares

I'm looking for an example to show my class. We are covering OLS vs GLS with autocorrelated errors -- I've got the class to the point where they understand (some of them) why the the [standard errors on the coefficient estimates tend to be underestimated (and the t-scores overestimated) when the autocorrelations of the errors at low lags are positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Regression_analysis). But it would be nice to have an example where they can see how inference might change based on fitting a ``better'' model with gls.

Thus, I'd like to show an example where the residuals from an OLS model y~x have an AR1 structure that would give spurious results (std errors on the estimates, p-values, etc.). Then I would show them a gls implementation that accounts for correlated residuals. E.g.,

```
# example of what'd I'd like given the right x and y 
ols1 <- lm(y~x) #ols model
summary(ols1) # would show a biased model
acf(residuals(ols1)) # would show AR1 structure
# vs
gls1 <- gls(y~x,correlation = corAR1())
```

Any ideas out there?

Edited for clarity.

Comment: What exactly do you believe to be biased when using OLS?

Comment: Ooops. Sorry. Not biased -- wrong wording. But rather with high AR [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Regression_analysis) tells me that ``the standard errors tend to be underestimated (and the t-scores overestimated) when the autocorrelations of the errors at low lags are positive.'' I guess I'm looking for an example where that would be the case that might impact how the regression would be interpreted.

Comment: Edited the original post.

Comment: OK, I see now - see my attempt below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little Monte Carlo simulation that illustrates that you will reject the null of a mean of zero way too often if you neglect the AR(1) autocorrelation in the time series generated , i.e., if you estimate the variance of the mean as $s^2/n$. GLS produces rejection rates closer to the nominal level. (I am not so familiar with the `nlme` package, so I hope I have used it wisely.)

```
library(nlme)

reps <- 1000
n <- 300

ols.rejections <- gls.rejections <- rep(NA,reps)

for (i in 1:reps){
  y <- arima.sim(n=n,list(ar=0.5))
  ols.reg <- lm(y~1)
  gls.reg <- gls(y~1,correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1))
  ols.rejections[i] <- summary(ols.reg)$coefficients[1,4] < 0.05
      gls.rejections[i] <- summary(gls.reg)$tTable[,"p-value"] < 0.05
}
```

The result:

```
> mean(ols.rejections)
[1] 0.264

> mean(gls.rejections)
[1] 0.046
```

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks much. From the simulations I've done the SE on the model coef lm(y~x+w) where w is AR(1) are pretty stable when OLS and GLS are compared. It's interesting. I have to think some more about it all.